# Enterprise software in which later versions have security vulnerability

Tags: root

Scenario : You are presented with a CVN which details that a piece of common software that you run with root privilege has a vulnerability that allows a non-privileged user to create or overwrite any file including files owned by root.

After further reading you find that the vulnerability only affects v1.6 and v1.7. The bug is fixed in v1.8 and the latest software is v1.9

However, you find that the version you are running across your Enterprise is v1.2 which is not affected by this vulnerability at all.

My question is this:

**Is it best practice to upgrade to a version beyond those versions that contain the vulnerability, even though the version you are using is not affected?**

I can foresee there might be different points of view.

On the one hand, by remaining at a version prior to the versions that are vulnerable, it is possible that the software is upgraded to a version that contains vulnerabilities due to human error. Let’s say that someone that looks after packaging does not spot this problem.

Yet on the other hand, one may say that we have to trust the processes and procedures in place which should prevent such human error.

Perhaps the answer to a large part is dependent on your appetite and assessment or risk. I’d really like to condense this down to a statement of best practice devoid of subjective belief.

Comment: Unless the the version 1.2 is LTS, upgrading to the lasted version is clearly your safest option.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to assume that risk assessments can be devoid of subjective belief.

The answer *is* to conduct a **risk assessment** based on all the factors involved and *infer* factors that matter to your risk assessment. There is no way to avoid subjective belief. And there is no "best practice" concerning when to update when there is no vulnerability in the present version.

Each software is unique, and moreover, each *update* to each software is unique. One cannot make a quantitative analysis on the probability of future bugs based on past bugs, or based on the bugs experienced by similar programs, for the very reasons you mention:

1. an update might fundamentally fix a faulty function that reduces the probability of future problems
2. each update can introduce new bugs

Yes, you can *infer* some relevant factors based on the updates, what was fixed, and other environmental factors, but that can require that one makes a lot of guesses. It can be better to review and test the code yourself, if that is possible, but that also requires that you trust your testing process. (If testing processes were a complete and objective measure, then software would not have any bugs, to begin with).

That means that *inference*, *experience*, and *expert opinion* are all important factors in making the decision to update from one version to another (and in all risk assessments).

Therefore, the best practice is to perform a risk assessment that includes the subjective beliefs of the experts whose opinions matter and the processes that you trust.